# How to import mantis project?

Tags: export, import

I need a help to export and import mantis project from a windows vm to windows server with all attachments.

Comment: That's 2 questions. Actually, it's no question at all.

Comment: If you have an answer for any of them, please help. @davidbaumann

Comment: You have to make one question for each question. Then, you have to be more specified, this way nobody can help you.

Comment: "I have a Debian VM and want to export the installation of mantis to a physical VM", for example.

Comment: Got it, will edit the question @davidbaumann

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm assuming you'll need to export it first. Does Mantis have a built-in export function? Have you used it? What is the official documentation for this process and have you followed that? https://support.mantishub.com/hc/en-us/sections/200904475-Importing-and-Exporting-Data

Comment: I've finished this as per my answer, Thanks to you @music2myear

Comment: Glad you were able to find the solution.

Comment: You can use the checkmark icon next to your answer to mark it as the answer. This helps others searching for similar questions to clearly identify the solution that worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this @music2myear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I've followed the next steps and it works:

1. Stop running servers for new mantis.
2. Copy the old mantis "data" folder which in mysql folder to the new mantis mysql folder"Rename the old one".
   3.Copy the config_inc.php file from the old mantis to the new one.
3. Start servers again.